# Request authentication at firestore rules always null with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

When a user wants to get his data he need to be authenticated. But when he retrieves data firestore doesn't let to get the data. I add a lot of debugs and in Unity the user is always authenticated and I get this [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdsrd.png).

Firebase initializes correctly and here is the code to get the user data

```
Debug.Log(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserID);
FDb.Collection("SavedGames").Document("SavedGames").Collection(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId).GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception);
            }
        });
```

And here are the Firestor rules

```
match /SavedGames/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAuth();
    }

function isAuth(){
            return request.auth != null;
        }
```

The Debug:

```
SPufxax5oJQXACF9wqRbBeBX1KG2
```

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Firestore.FirestoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions.
  at Firebase.Firestore.Internal.Util.FlattenAndThrowException (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask) [0x0003d] in Z:\tmp\tmp.DnKB31Zq3X\firebase\firestore\client\unity\proxy\Util.cs:97 
  at Firebase.Firestore.Internal.Util+<MapResult>c__AnonStorey0`2[T,U].<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] completedTask) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.DnKB31Zq3X\firebase\firestore\client\unity\proxy\Util.cs:59 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Firestore.FirestoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions.
  at Firebase.Firestore.Internal.Util.FlattenAndThrowException (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask) [0x0003d] in Z:\tmp\tmp.DnKB31Zq3X\firebase\firestore\client\unity\proxy\Util.cs:97 
  at Firebase.Firestore.Internal.Util+<MapResult>c__AnonStorey0`2[T,U].<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] completedTask) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.DnKB31Zq3X\firebase\firestore\client\unity\proxy\Util.cs:59 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 <---

UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
FirebaseFirestoreManager/<>c:<ReadData>b__17_1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Firebase.Firestore.QuerySnapshot>) (at Assets/Scripts/MirariaId/FirebaseFirestoreManager.cs:116)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 <---

UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
FirebaseFirestoreManager/<>c:<ReadData>b__17_1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Firebase.Firestore.QuerySnapshot>) (at Assets/Scripts/MirariaId/FirebaseFirestoreManager.cs:116)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
```

I can write data but i can't retrieve it.

Also I have tried to put the rules to true instead isAuth() and it works.

I have tried with firebase sdk 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 8.0.0 and 8.1.0
and I use Unity 2020.3.14f1(LTS).

Comment: In my experience the security rules are typically right when they make this claim. If you log `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId` right before you access the database, what does that show?

Comment: Hello thanks for trying to help me,
As I have mentioned before the user is correctly logged in, so it shows the user's ID.

Comment: Good to hear you already checked that. Can you edit your question to show that code, and its output?

Comment: Already updated, I also realized that I can write data but I can't retrieve it

Comment: Hmmm.... that all looks fine at first glance, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Hopefully somebody else spots it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back,

I downgraded the sdk to 7.0.2 and now it works fine!

I don't know why but it is correct.